# On hover border radius is not applying to card

Tags: flutter, dart

On hover, I'm trying to change the color of a card. Using the hover property in Theme data, I achieved that, but for my card **border-radius is not applying on hover**,

Hover is applying with sharp corners as shown below

[image: On hover]

**Theme Configuration :**

```
  theme: ThemeData(
    hoverColor: Colors.green,
    cardTheme: CardTheme(
      color: Colors.white,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(16),
      shadowColor: Colors.greenAccent,
      elevation: 5,
      surfaceTintColor: Colors.white,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

**Card :**

```
Card(
        child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {},
            child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: Wrap(
                  runSpacing: 5,
                  children: [
                    Icon(Icons.memory),
                    RichText(
                      text: TextSpan(
                          text: 'Title : ',
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleSmall,
                          children: [
                            TextSpan(
                                text: 'Memory',
                                style:
                                    Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium)
                          ]),
                    ),
                    RichText(
                      softWrap: true,
                      text: TextSpan(
                          text: 'Des : ',
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleSmall,
                          children: [
                            TextSpan(
                                text:
                                    'Currently used memory 250 GB remaining is 250 GB ..... !!!!',
                                style:
                                    Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium)
                          ]),
                    )
                  ],
                ))))
```

[Dart Pad Reference Code](https://dartpad.dev/?id=91ca1604da3418c3fce0fd0fa10ba2c3)

Comment: `Card(clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias, ...`

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve your required behaviour is to simply use a ***[`customBorder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkResponse/customBorder.html)*** property which is present on `InkWell` Widget.

```dart
// ...Rest of code
child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {},
                customBorder: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                ),
// ...rest of code
```

***[DART DEMO](https://dartpad.dev/?id=9040027a23114143fa54428a713a10dc)***