# Update animation based on mouse position

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have a Flutter web app with an `AnimationController` that needs to animate to a new value based on the position of the mouse, and the animation needs to have a curve. I'm updating the animation by calling `animateTo` in the `onPointerHover` callback of a `Listener`. However, the animation isn't updating while the mouse is in motion, and is only updating once the mouse comes to rest after being moved.

Here's a minimal reproducible example, which I'm running on the web.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MouseAnimationApp());
}

class MouseAnimationApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MouseAnimationApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MouseAnimationApp> createState() => _MouseAnimationAppState();
}

class _MouseAnimationAppState extends State<MouseAnimationApp>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final _controller = AnimationController(vsync: this);

  void _updatePosition(double globalPosition) {
    _controller.animateTo(
      globalPosition / MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      curve: Curves.easeOutQuart,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 700),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Listener(
        onPointerHover: (event) => _updatePosition(event.position.dy),
        child: AnimatedBuilder(
          animation: _controller,
          builder: (_, __) => ColoredBox(
            color: Color.lerp(Colors.red, Colors.black, _controller.value)!,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Result**

[image: Screen recording]

**Expected Result:** The background color animates smoothly as the mouse is moved.

**Actual Result:** The background color only animates once the mouse stops moving.

**Note:** this is just an example to demonstrate the problem. This specific use case (changing the background color) could be solved without animation just by updating the background color whenever the mouse moves. However, I need to use a complex animation in my app and my question is specifically about updating an animation with a curve based on mouse position.

Comment: Check the link in my answer. Hope that is correct for you. If not let me know. I'll post the whole code and you can run from your end. Sorry initially I posted some other link because somehow the update was not done properly

Comment: Unfortunately, your code doesn't solve my issue — the background color still doesn't update while the mouse is in motion, and only updates once the mouse stops moving. See my comment on your answer.

Comment: Sorry my previous answer was garbage, i did not read your question properly.
Maybe animation is not your best friend in this case.
This code is just a sketch, but if you like it,you can build on this
https://dartpad.dev/?id=91ca1604da3418c3fce0fd0fa10ba2c3

Comment: @Csisanyi No worries at all. It seems like this code is from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77381872/on-hover-border-radius-is-not-applying-to-card/77381918#77381918) question, which changes a widget when it's hovered. Unfortunately, this isn't related to my question since it doesn't involve the mouse's position. Also, I need to use animation since the update to the UI needs to be animated along the curve `Curves.easeOutQuart`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    void main() {
      runApp(const MaterialApp(home: MouseAnimationApp()));
    }
    
    class MouseAnimationApp extends StatefulWidget {
      const MouseAnimationApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      State<MouseAnimationApp> createState() => _MouseAnimationAppState();
    }
    
    class _MouseAnimationAppState extends State<MouseAnimationApp>
        with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
      late final _controller = AnimationController(vsync: this);
    
      void _updatePosition(double globalPosition) {
        _controller.animateTo(
          globalPosition / MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          curve: Curves.easeOutQuart,
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 50),
        );
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Listener(
          onPointerHover: (event) {
            print("${event.position.dy}");
            _updatePosition(event.position.dy);
          },
          child: AnimatedBuilder(
            animation: _controller,
            builder: (_, __) => ColoredBox(
              color: Color.lerp(Colors.red, Colors.black, _controller.value)!,
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: This code is functionally identical to the code I provided in my question and does not solve my issue. The only differences between your code and the code I provided are: 1) creating a `MaterialApp` in the `main` method rather than the build method of `MouseAnimationApp`; 2) adding a `print` statement; and 3) changing the duration of the animation from 700ms to 50ms.

None of these changes affect the output of the code. Running your code at https://dartpad.dev confirms that your code doesn't solve my issue — the background color still doesn't until the mouse stops moving.

Comment: It about the animation time. Make it 0ms and you will see instant updated while hovering.
You see it like color changes when hovering ends because before animation is complete mouse position offset changes. So another animation starts..like this you only see the last animation to finish and change color when mouse position offset is stable at the end.

Comment: You're right that if you make the animation duration 0ms that you will see the background properly update when moving the mouse (although making it 50ms like in your example still doesn't work). However, this removes any animations, and my question is specifically about driving an animation with the mouse position. This problem also isn't caused by the fact that `animateTo` is being called every frame and overriding the previous animation. If you create a `Ticker` and have it call `animateTo` every frame to change the background color, the background color updates correctly.